# Bigquery "Not a Leaf Field" Error

Tags: google-bigquery

This query:

```
SELECT payload.pages FROM FLATTEN([publicdata:samples.github_nested] , payload)
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 1000
```

Results in this error:

```
Error: Field payload.pages from table publicdata:samples.github_nested is not a leaf field.
```

Is this a bug or or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#flatten

First, you need to give `FLATTEN` a repeated field to flatten. `payload` isn't repeated. `payload.pages` is. Second, `payload.pages`, in your select statement, isn't a leaf field, it is a nested / repeated one. So you switch it to use `payload.pages.*`

So your query would become:

```
SELECT payload.pages.* 
FROM FLATTEN([publicdata:samples.github_nested] , payload.pages)
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 1000
```